# Error while querying from access in Excel

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I need to create an excel sheet that takes a series of characters and numbers as an input, checks it against an Access database and then returns a value that corresponds to the 7th column of the same row of the database. I do not know much of VBA, and i managed to compile this code, taking tidbits from various sources such as StackOverflow, MS Office website, ExelForum, and AllenBrowne.com

However, when I run the code, I get an error, "No value given for one or more required parameters", and frankly speaking, I am stumped as to where exactly the error is originating at, and why it is doing so.

My code is as follows:

```
   Sub Query()
   On Error GoTo errhandler:
   Dim con As String
   Dim sql As String
   Dim inputc 

   con = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" _
         & "Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=" & Jet4x _
         & "; Data Source=" & "C:\Path\file.mdb;"

   Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
   Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

   inputc = Range("B1").Value

   sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE 'Custno' = " & input & ";" 

   Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

   cn.Open con
   cn.Execute sql

   Set rs = new ADODB.Recordset

   rs.Open sql, cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic

   Debug.Print rs.Fields("7")

   MsgBox rs.Fields("7")

   Exit Sub

   errhandler: MsgBox Err.Description

   End Sub
```

Any help provided is highly appreciated.

-A

Changed the code to this but now have an error that no values match:

```
  Sub Query()
   On Error GoTo errhandler:
   Dim con As String
   Dim sql As String
   Dim inputc 

   con = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" _
         & "Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=" & Jet4x _
         & "; Data Source=" & "C:\Path\file.mdb;"

   Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
   Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

   inputc = Range("B1").Value

   sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE 'Custno' = 'inputc';" 

   Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

   cn.Open con
   cn.Execute sql

   Set rs = new ADODB.Recordset

   rs.Open sql, cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic

   Debug.Print rs.Fields("7")

   MsgBox rs.Fields("7")

   Exit Sub

   errhandler: MsgBox Err.Description

   End Sub
```

I have checked the values and am searching for values that exist in the database.

Comment: Remove the single-quotes from around "Custno" and insert them around `input`?

Comment: Nope, that doest work. -A

Comment: Can you please try commenting out `On Error GoTo errhandler:` and tell us if any line is highlighted when it's throwing the error?

Comment: When i try that, it highlights `& "Jet OLEDB: Engine Type=" & Jet4x _` and says `Jet4x` Variable not defined

Comment: So where do you set the Jet4x variable to a value?

Comment: @LanceRoberts, The problem is that Jet4x is an engine, not a variable. When I do rs.Recordcount with the same code, it works perfectly.

Comment: If it's the exact name then don't quote it out.

Comment: I don't see the need for the cn.Execute line.  The rs.Open statement is the one that uses the sql.

Comment: @LanceRoberts Even removing that has no effect, and same goes for not quoting out Jet4x.

Comment: You need to figure out what line it is breaking on.  Go though it line by line (F8) and see where it fails.

Comment: It may be that you're back to the single quote problem now that you've solved the others.

Comment: Its breaking on the line `Debug.Print rs.Fields("7")`

Comment: I would wonder why you have 7 in quotes myself.  By the way, separate from the problem, don't forget to close your recordset and connection, and set them both to nothing when your done.

Comment: ok, will do. And btw, how do i output the seventh column in the same row that the customer number is found?

Comment: I have that 7 there because i want the 7th column's output to be shown. Is that incorrect?

Comment: 7 should work, but if you quote it then it's looking for a field called 7.

Comment: I removed the quotes, and there is the error 3021 popping up

Comment: Did you also remove it from the next line?

Comment: Yup! removed them from both

Comment: Well the next thing to do is check is your recordset actually got any values.  You could also try using the actual fieldname (in quotes).  I gotta go to bed, good luck.

Comment: Now the error im getting is "Either EOF or BOF is true, or the current record has been deleted. Requested operation requires a current record." Probably means that the mdb file is missing data. Thanks a bunch! Please add it as an answer so that i can mark it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Public variables:

```
Public db As DAO.Database
Public rsttemp As DAO.Recordset
Public acApp As Access.Application
```

Check if the database exist and open it:

```
Sub CheckDB() 
    'database path
    s = "C:\Path\file.mdb"   
    If db Is Nothing Then
        Set acApp = New Access.Application
        acApp.OpenCurrentDatabase s
        Set db = acApp.CurrentDb
    End If
End Sub
```

close DB

```
Sub CloseDB()
    If Not acApp Is Nothing Then
        acApp.CloseCurrentDatabase
    End If
End Sub
```

Main Sub where you open the recordset

```
Sub SqlExecute()

    Call CheckDB

    inputc = Range("B1").Value
    sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE Custno = """ & inputc & """;"
    Set rsttemp = db.OpenRecordset(sql, dbOpenSnapshot)

    MsgBox "Records count: " & rsttemp.RecordCount
    MsgBox rsttemp.Fields("7")
    rsttemp.Close
    Set rsttemp = Nothing

    Call CloseDB
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked much better than Lance's Solution! (No offence to you, Lance; Thanks a lot for helping me out!)

Comment: Though, I did change one part of the code, made it compatible with all devices:
`Sub CheckDB()

s = "C:\Path\File.mdb"

If db is Nothing then

Set db= OpenDatabase(s)

End If

End Sub`

Answer (score 0):

- First check your variable object is inputc or input
- Check if inputc is null ?
- If column custno is numeric then use Custno = " & input & " or if text than use  Custno = '" & input & "'

Comment: It is inputc, and it is a mixture of text and numbers, like ABCD1234

Comment: try this one SQL = "SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE Custno = '" & inputc & "';"

Comment: Problem with constring, refer to this link [link](http://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-jet-ole-db-4-0/)

Comment: That did solve the Jet4x issue, but now I'm getting this error: "Application-defined or object defined error." with the runtime error number 3021

Comment: @user3094302, you need to show us the line where the error occurred for any particular error.

Comment: No line is being highlighted. Im at a loss as to what to do.

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

Remove the cn.Execute line
Use the field name in the Print and MsgBox statements (in quotes)
Put Jet4X inside the quotes since it is not a variable

Also make sure to close your connection and recordset and set to Nothing at the end.